# The “View larger map” text in the Google Maps widget keep changing

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Issue is only in Internet Explorer, not in Chrome or Firefox: The “View larger map” text in the Google Maps widget keep changing. With each page refresh, one of the “View larger map” texts will be smaller/a different font from the other two. The odd link out changes positions with each page refresh.

[image]

Comment: Is this something you're trying to manipulate, or is this just a stock element from Google Maps? If it's a stock element I'd suggest that you may be observing an A/B test by Google.

Comment: It is a stock element by google but behaving like i have mentioned in question only in IE. i had searched google for this issue but nothing useful information was found